# Cannot dual Windows XP and Ubuntu

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-xp

I am new to Ubuntu and at the moment I am trying to get Ubuntu 12.10 to one of my machines. The machine is a Pentium 4 @ 3.06, 2Gb RAM, 200GB Hard Drive and a NVidia GeForce 8800 GT.

A few days ago, I tried Ubuntu without installing and it worked perfectly. Yesterday, I decided to formatted the hard drive and divide my hard drive into four partitions: 1 for the XP, 1 for Ubuntu, 1 for swamp and 1 where I will have my documents.

Everything went great, I installed XP and then Ubuntu but I did something wrong on the partition window (Ubuntu partition window) that I ended up without boot loader.  This morning, I formatted everything again, installed XP and when I went to install Ubuntu (with the same DVD as before) the problems started.

First, I had a black screen with a message written with white text saying something like:

> unable to find a medium containing a live file system.

After I burned another CD and tried again, I got stuck at the red dots (loading screen).  I then went online and I read somewhere that it could be the CD, so I checked the integrity of the CD and everything was fine.  I also unplugged all USBs connected to the computer and nothing changed.

I googled further options to try to solve my problem and some users suggested that people having these types of problems should try the alternate installation, which if I am not wrong is for networks. I then tried to install and yes the installation process was different from the normal CD, but it did get stuck on a page where it was doing something, like: `...finding ethd0` and it was stuck on the 100%.

I tried USB installation as well and it also got stuck at the red dots (I do not have USB 3.0 on the computer in question).

I have burned 5 different CD's and all at low speed. I checked the integrity and all are fine. I downloaded other distribution as well as other versions of Ubuntu and I still cannot install or even run the Live CD of Ubuntu or any other distribution.

What is really annoying me is that everything was working perfectly before, when I first tried to install Ubuntu.

**Edit:**

My boot load is normal, no errors and all the hardware is working fine.

I forgot to mention that after the loading screen (red dots) gets stuck, the DVD drive and the hard drive goes into idle state. I also restored the default values of the BIOS and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to read boot process messages. Start ubuntu without "quiet splash" and kernel command line.
2. Try to read logs from booting system
3. Look for I/O errors in logs. They tell that your cd or hdd have hardware problems.
4. If you messed up partition table try to erase your hdd boot sector. Use dd if=/dev/zero of=/your/hdd bs=1M count=1 It will wipe all data! Or without count=1 to erase all hdd to the end.
5. It's much better idea to install windows on one drive and linux on second and use grub or bios boot menu to switch booting.

Comment: I do not have any type of error while booting up.          
If my partition table was broken I couldn't access XP, right?

Comment: Your 5th point, @Dmitryilyin, is only your opinion, not a valid point.  Installing both to one drive is also a valid idea, if you know what you're doing at install time.  Although the installer is pretty smart, with resizing, though.

Comment: @FabioMachado if your partition table was messed, you wouldn't be able to access XP, yes.  So that's not your issue.